# How do you evaluate the integral by making an appropriate change of variables?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Evaluate the integral by making an appropriate change of variables.

$$\iint_R \cos\left(\frac{y-x}{y+x}\right)dA$$

with $R$ defined by $x\geq 0$, $y\geq 0$, and $1\leq x+y\leq 2$.

I found $u = y-x$ and $v = y+x$ but now how do I find the boundaries of $u$ and $v$ to evaluate the double integral?

Comment: I've edited your question to have mathematical notation in it. Please check to make sure I've converted it correctly.

Comment: 7 questions later, and you still haven't honored your promise which you posted in response to the comments [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/380717/9003). 20 questions in all, and no accepted answers? Why keep asking questions if you are not finding answers helpful? What else can we conclude other than you must not appreciate any of the many answers you've received; it is certainly discouraging to users who might *otherwise* be willing to answer and/or continue to help.

Answer (score 1):

Let's draw a nice plot of the area:

[image]

By doing a simple way , we can find that $$x\ge 0,~y\ge 0,~1\le x+y\le 2\longrightarrow 1\le v\le 2,~\frac{-v}2\le u\le \frac{v}2$$ So we have the following changed double integrals instead to solve:

$$\int_{v=1}^{2}\int_{u=-v/2}^{v/2}\cos(u/v)J(x,y) dudv$$ For finding $J(x,y)$ see [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobian_matrix_and_determinant).